# Friends of a friend with different tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following question:

Let us consider a social network scenario: passengers in the same cruise trip are considered to be “friends”, find friends of friend of Douglas.

I tried solving it using the following code, but it's not working. It will return Douglas and his friends, not the cruisers who are friends of Douglas's friends.

```
   SELECT PASSENGERNUM
FROM VOYAGE
WHERE CRUISENUM
IN (

SELECT CRUISENUM
FROM VOYAGE
WHERE PASSENGERNUM
IN (

SELECT PASSENGERNUM
FROM PASSENGER
WHERE PASSENGERNAME !=  'Douglas'
AND PASSENGERNAME
IN (

SELECT PASSENGERNAME
FROM PASSENGER
WHERE PASSENGERNUM
IN (

SELECT PASSENGERNUM
FROM VOYAGE
WHERE CRUISENUM
IN (

SELECT CRUISENUM
FROM VOYAGE
WHERE PASSENGERNUM
IN (

SELECT passengernum
FROM PASSENGER
WHERE passengername =  'Douglas'
)
)
)
)
)
)
```

This what I got which is only passengernum of Douglas and his friend only instead of Douglas's friend passangernum

```
PASSENGERNUM
11797
11797
11797
12345
12345
```

This is the database table (passenger, voyage):
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0I8D.png

[image: Cruise database schema]

Comment: I would recommend spending some time getting familiar with using [JOINs in SQL](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database)... it will make solving this problem much much cleaner / simpler.

Comment: Please edit the question and include test data which demonstrates the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The question, while probably poorly explained and presented, is still fairly interesting

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want something like this:

```
select p2.*
  from passenger p1 
    inner join voyage v1 
      on p1.passengernum = v1.passengernum
     inner join voyage v2
       on v1.cruisenum = v2.cruisenum
     inner join voyage v3
       on v2.passengernum = v3.passengernum and v2.passengernum <> p1.passengernum
     inner join voyage v4
       on v3.cruisenum = v4.cruisenum and v4.cruisenum <> v1.cruisenum
     inner join passenger p2 
       ON v4.passengernum = p2.passengernum
  where p1.passengername = 'douglas' and v4.passengernum <> v2.passengernum;
```

1. By way of explanation, you start by finding the voyagers that each passenger has been on (inner join 1).
2. You then find the other people on each of those voyages (inner join 2)
3. and then you find the other voyages that those people were on, unless the person is the same person as the original voyage (inner join 3)
4. and then you find the other people, on THOSE voyages (except where the voyage is the same as the first voyage) (inner join 4)
5. and we then limit it to the person of interest, and to people who were only on the other voyages, not the first one.

Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d59b9/15. I make no claim that this is in any way perfect or optimised, but it looks to give correct results.